# How to make a new syntax highlight in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting, tmlanguage

I am tring to make a new programming language called 'ZE' so i made some basics and i am tring to make the syntax hightlight so i learned the basics from here[text](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars)
and made the syntaxes using yo code that is my tmlanguage file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "ze Programming Language",
    "foldingStartMarker" : "\\{\\s*$",
    "foldingStopMarker" : "^\\s*\\}",   

    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#comment"
        },

        {
            "include": "#strings"
        },
        {
            "include": "#keywords"
        {
    ],
    "repository": {
        "#comment":{
            "name":"comment.line.double-slash",
            "begin": "\/\/",
            "end":"\\.*"
        },
        "keywords": {
            "patterns": [{
                "name": "keyword.control.ze",
                "match": "\\b(if|while|for|return)\\b"
            }]
        },
        "strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.double.ze",
            "begin": "\"",
            "end": "\"",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.ze",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.ze"
}
```

i was just was tring if it will work

i placed it in the extentsions place and i checked my extentsions in vscode and it was there so i created .ze
file but nothing just happenend so far

Comment: where _exactly_ did you put it?